# Database connection using OCILIB

Tags: c, oracle-call-interface

***Hi everyone,
I am new to C language,
I have connected the database using  OCILIB, and I have found this Program on net.***

```
#include "ocilib.h"
#include <conio.h>

/* Example on Microsoft platform */

static HANDLE evt;

void long_oracle_call(void *data)
{
 OCI_Statement *st  = OCI_StatementCreate((OCI_Connection *) data); 
OCI_Resultset *rs;

/* execute a query that takes a long time to process */

OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, "select * from employees2");

rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);

while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))
{
    printf("%i - %s", OCI_GetInt(rs, 1), OCI_GetString(rs, 2));
}

SetEvent(evt);
}


int main(void)
{
 OCI_Connection *cn;

if (!OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("localhost:1522/infodba", "system", "infodba",      OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
 evt = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);

 _beginthread(long_oracle_call, 0, cn);

  if (WaitForSingleObject(evt, 10000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    OCI_Break(cn);
    Sleep(2000);
  }

  OCI_Cleanup();
  getch();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

IT works fine but I want the output of this program into an charter array,instead of below line

```
printf("%i - %s", OCI_GetInt(rs, 1), OCI_GetString(rs, 2));
```

I tried to do that,
test[1]=OCI_GetString(rs, 2);

But it is giving me error as

```
ERROR: A value of type "const text*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type   "char".
```

Somebody please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a *string* to a `char[]` arrary using `=` <sup>#</sup>. You've to do like

```
strcpy(test, OCI_GetString(rs, 2));
```

assuming, `text` is a sufficient-length `char` array.

<sup># Other than initialization time</sup>